# Меню с динамическим количеством кнопок в зависимости от ширины

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго.

[Описать искомое могу примерно так](http://jsfiddle.net/ma9qr46h/).

Сейчас начинают появляться 'резиновые дизайны', в которых при изменении ширины страницы, в большую или в меньшую сторону, скажем, в горизонтальном меню становится меньше или больше пунктов (кнопок), и есть доп. кнопка, в которую эти пункты помещены. Удобно! Хочется приобщиться к современным веяниям, но то ли для для гугла я не знаю слов, то ли гугл не может найти соотв. пример.

Может ли кто подсказать ссылкой, словами для гугла или примером кода, чтобы найти описанное выше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример кода скинуть не могу, но вот [пример реализации](http://arxip.com/) пожалуйста.

Как мне кажется, там все повешано на window.resize и при уменьшении окна браузера несколько последних пунктов меню просто перетаскиваются в отдельный список.

Comment: За пример сойдет! Честно говоря, сталкивался с более нагроможденным кодом, и не въехал